# Tag pair indicator

Tags: tags, html-parsing

Is there a software that can be used to highlight/match up tag pairs within a (web) document - indicating the starting and closing tags(e.g `<div>....</div>`, `{...}`, etc. ), even when tags are nested?

Comment: Do you know of an IDE that does that. The ones I know don't.

Comment: Visual Studio does when the cursor is on a tag.